# I want just to run a line of code without t()

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

How I can run this line of code without this t() ??

```
$severity_options[$severity] = t('@description', array('@description' => drupal_ucfirst($severity),
```

Comment: Translates strings to the current locale - https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/t/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to remove the `t` function and add `check_plain`.

The `@description` variable is replaced with the `drupal_ucfirst($severity)`, so you can only encode special characters.

```
$severity_options[$severity] =  check_plain(drupal_ucfirst($severity))
```